# Html5 webm video seeking

Tags: html5-video, webm

i have simple html5 video player like this

```
<video id="video" controls="true" src="video.webm"></video>
```

If the 'video.webm' is some professional webm video (for example movie trailer), seeking works by downloading only requested parts, if i put my own encoded webm video, upon seeking browser first downloads whole file before seeks.

From http requests i have observed that partial http requests are working correctly for professional video, but for my video the browser always asks for whole file.

- what is missing in my webm video for browser to ask for specific byte-range?

Comment: What tool are you using to encode your video?

Comment: @TimHayes I have tried Miro video converter and XMedia recode

Comment: I'm not familiar with XMedia, but I believe Miro uses FFMpeg to encode in the background. Unfortunately I don't think you have access to the command line params when you use that. But I'd give Lou's suggestions a shot. Do you have a sample of your video on the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, seeking-behavior will depend on the keyframe rate of the encoded video. If you're using FFMpeg to do the encodes, have a look here: http://wiki.webmproject.org/ffmpeg

The parameter to note is `-g`, which sets the maximum number of *interframes* allowed before the encoder must set an *intraframe* (a keyframe) -- whether it feels it needs to or not. The value to choose is a matter of taste and tradeoffs, so you must experiment and decide for yourself. Perhaps start with a value of `360`, and work downward if needed.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the webm wiki. It lists the keyint_min as being the "maximum keyframe interval (frames)" whereas ffmpeg lists it as the "minimum interval between IDR-frames" (http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html). That seems contradictory. Do you know why? I was going to suggest setting the -g (group of pictures) param using a smaller parameter too.

Comment: Ahem. It appears the descriptions for `-g` and `-keyint_min` were reversed. Will edit my reply, above.